# CSS resize on table cells does not allow width reduction

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have the following code [here](http://codepen.io/Kyzcreig/pen/NqoRVJ/):

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  resize: both;
}
td {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  margin: 0px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
div {
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br>

<div></div>
```

It doesn't work in Chrome, Safari or IE.

- If you re-size the width of the top-left cell, and then re-size the width of the middle-left cell it will not let you downsize the width.
- If you try to downsize via the top-left cell again it will not work
  either.

How should I fix it?

Comment: CSS doesn't have bugs, only browser do. If you want a browser bug fixed, file a bug report with the vendors having the problem.

Comment: Sure CSS has bugs, just like any language.  With pretty much every vendor having issues my suspicion is that there's a dearth of documentation of resize for tables, if it is indeed an issue with vendors.

Comment: That's a bit of a stretch, especially given the declarative nature of CSS. Perhaps it has limited/unexpected/poor design choices, but CSS by itself is just a specification.

Comment: Anyhow, if vendors are following the spec, and the feature you are trying to use does not cover your use case, then you might consider contacting the CSS Working Group if you think it worthy enough.

Comment: Good idea.  I sent Bert an email.  We'll see how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you resize an element using the [CSS `resize` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/resize), a CSS height/width are applied inline to that table cell.

Example:

[image: Example]
[image: Example markup]

Now, let's resize the cell below it so that the width is smaller:

[image: Example 2]
[image: Example markup 2]

It doesn't work, the width of the top cell does not change and the column remains the width of its largest cell.

This particular behaviour is not a bug, it is a limitation of the `resize` property. To get the result that you want, you would need to **adjust the width of all the cells in the column, when one is resized**. This would require javascript.

**Note:** I'm not saying that Chrome (tested 44.0.2403.130 m) doesn't have bugs using the `resize` property on table cells, it does display very buggy behaviour.

Comment: Is there a solution to this resizing problem? How do I fix it using JS? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the bug is your code. You may not to allow resize tables and tds. You can resize divs inside your td and it was correct. Table and cell resizing is not allowed in firefox and in webkit browsers it is dangerous.

You can make something like this:

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><div></div></td>
            <td><div></div></td>
            <td><div></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div></div></td>
            <td><div></div></td>
            <td><div></div></td>        
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div></div></td>
            <td><div></div></td>
            <td><div></div></td>       
        </tr>   
    </table>
    <br>
    <div></div>
```

And the css

```
    table, td { resize: none; }
    table td div { min-width: 50px; min-height: 50px; resize: both; }
```

Comment: what's dangerous about resizing table data?  also, I tried divs but it's really not the same effect: http://codepen.io/Kyzcreig/pen/XbONjp

Comment: Maybe if you remove td paddings and div borders it has same effect... It is dangerous because it is not recommended by W3C and it is not in the official specification. You test it and it works very bad.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude - Where in the specifications does it say that it is not recommended for table cells? All I see is "Applies to: elements with overflow other than visible"

Comment: I'm getting the same behavior, where if you resize the width of the top left and then resize the width on the middle left, you can't downsize the width anymore.

Comment: @veta is because I miss remove `resize:both` from the tds. Sorry. See again: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGMRdX

Comment: @misterManSam you can view this: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/resize and this:  http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/CR-css-ui-3-20150707/ . It's not allowed to elements that overflow is visible. In `<td>` maybe not, but in `<table>` defined with overflow hidden is a bad practice.

Comment: No dice for me Marcos.  The divs work fine but the table cells still freeze up.  And then you have divs and cells of different sizes.

Comment: What browser do you use? I test in Firefox 39, Chrome 44 and IE 11 and it works. Note than the divs inside the tds has a min-width and min-height value that I've writting for visibility purposes.